# CMake/JOM not building in parallel

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

Something that has worked consistently in the past is not working for me now.  I have always been able to build in parallel using a combination of Qt Creator, Jom, and the Visual Studio 14(2015) compiler.

I generate using NMake Makefiles, but set the CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM to jom.  I don't use the generator that CMake provides, "NMake Makefiles JOM" because Qt Creator can't seem to parse the output - i.e. I don't get the project hierarchy displayed.  But I am confident the way I am doing this now has worked for me in the past, but now it only compiles sequentially for me.

I modify the build step in QtC from the default

```
cmake --build . --target all
```

to

```
cmake --build . --target all -- -j8
```

in order to pass the -j8 to jom.

I notice two things:
The generated Makefile has .NOTPARALLEL near the top
which I believe causes the output when JOM starts,

```
jom: parallel job execution disabled for Makefile
```

However when I manually comment out the .NOTPARALLEL I *still* get sequential compilation.

Any ideas on what's happening here?
For CXX_FLAGS, I'm using /MP flag and not using /Gm flag - I understand these are incompatible

EDIT: Qt Creator version 4.5 and CMake 3.6.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: A minimal example that shows your problem might be helpful. Have updated on of the tools causing this change?

Comment: I realize this is a poor stack overflow question.  I've got another PC with Qt and CMake configured and found a completely unrelated project that builds in parallel on one machine but not the one in question.  I'm going to hunt the difference down and post it here in hopes of helping somebody in the future if they have the same configuration snafu.  For reference, the project I used for comparison was a small program called QWar I put on Github under my name.  It's interesting to me that on the 2nd machine that works in parallel the Makefile still has .NOTPARALLEL.

Comment: I've discovered that the CPU clock speed is stuck at 0.78 GHz, which makes it look like it flatlines at about 25% of available CPU usage.  That's why it appeared to be using only 1 core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builds were flat-lining at about 25% of total CPU available - hence my misdiagnosis that build was being done sequentially.  The *actual* problem was hardware-related.  Some event triggered a hardware-level limiting of the CPU clock (stuck at 0.78GHz).  Pulling the battery of my Dell Precision 5510 for 15 seconds and reconnecting did the trick.

Comment: You are lucky. I have same issue, but on my PC (very powerful). I have an idea that it depends on how much actual files are in project, but I'm not sure.